# Copy-paste special VBA does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy-paste special values and formatting from multiple workbooks into a master spreadsheet. The number of columns is the same in the source and destination and the number of rows varies.

I read the other threads on this and tried multiple ways (including defining a range in the destination file) but I still cannot make the paste special work. Below is my code:

```
Sub mergefiles()

Dim folderpath As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim erow As Long


folderpath = "D:\Test\"
filepath = folderpath & "*.xls*"
filename = Dir(filepath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While filename <> ""

  Workbooks.Open (folderpath & filename)

  Worksheets("EmplOffers").ShowAllData

  lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  ActiveWorkbook.Close

  erow = Worksheets("EmplOffers").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1,     0).Row

  Worksheets("EmplOffers").Range(Cells(erow, 3), Cells(erow, 20)).PasteSpecial=:xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

  filename = Dir

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it giving you an error or acting unexpectedly?

Comment: It simply doesn't copy-paste anything. Just looks like it's selecting the range but not doing the actual copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the paste call:

```
Worksheets("EmplOffers").Range(Cells(erow, 3).Address).PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great!

Comment: @Ioana if you wouldn't mind, mark my answer as correct to remove this from the unanswered question queue

Answer (score 0):

A named parameter should precede := 
 **Change**

```
Worksheets("EmplOffers").Range(Cells(erow, 3), Cells(erow, 20)).PasteSpecial=:xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

**To:**

```
Worksheets("EmplOffers").Range(Cells(erow, 3), Cells(erow, 20)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works as well!